# grpc-spring-boot-starter - netty server does not start if I add spring-boot-starter-jdbc to the dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

I'm starting to test grpc with spring boot, I'm using the GrpcService available in net.devh:grpc-spring-boot-starter (https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/).

It works fine isolated, like, if I add it to a project and build a GrpcService, netty starts fine and the service is available. My gradle.build

```
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id( "com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.18"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val isLocal: String? by project

repositories {

... my repos
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("net.devh:grpc-spring-boot-starter:2.14.0.RELEASE")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.23.4"
    }

    generatedFilesBaseDir = "${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/src/generated"

    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.58.0"
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("grpc") {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
2024-01-18 07:42:26.245  INFO 15644 --- [           main] org.example.ApplicationKt                : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-18 07:42:27.385  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.c.a.GrpcClientAutoConfiguration  : Detected grpc-netty-shaded: Creating ShadedNettyChannelFactory + InProcessChannelFactory
2024-01-18 07:42:28.010  INFO 15644 --- [           main] g.s.a.GrpcServerFactoryAutoConfiguration : Detected grpc-netty-shaded: Creating ShadedNettyGrpcServerFactory
2024-01-18 07:42:28.086  INFO 15644 --- [           main] g.s.a.GrpcServerFactoryAutoConfiguration : 'grpc.server.in-process-name' is set: Creating InProcessGrpcServerFactory
2024-01-18 07:42:28.279  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.tests.PingService, bean: pingService, class: org.example.PingService
2024-01-18 07:42:28.279  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.health.v1.Health, bean: grpcHealthService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.HealthServiceImpl
2024-01-18 07:42:28.279  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection, bean: protoReflectionService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService
2024-01-18 07:42:28.465  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.GrpcServerLifecycle          : gRPC Server started, listening on address: *, port: 9090
2024-01-18 07:42:28.470  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.tests.PingService, bean: pingService, class: org.example.PingService
2024-01-18 07:42:28.471  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.health.v1.Health, bean: grpcHealthService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.HealthServiceImpl
2024-01-18 07:42:28.471  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection, bean: protoReflectionService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService
2024-01-18 07:42:28.474  INFO 15644 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.GrpcServerLifecycle          : gRPC Server started, listening on address: in-process:test, port: -1
2024-01-18 07:42:28.493  INFO 15644 --- [           main] org.example.ApplicationKt                : Started ApplicationKt in 3.012 seconds (JVM running for 3.829)
```

But, if I change the dependencies and add spring-boot-starter-jdbc, the GrpcService does not start, it is like Netty doesn't start:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("net.devh:grpc-spring-boot-starter:2.14.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:3.1.5")
    implementation("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.4.1.jre8")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}
```

```
2024-01-18T07:46:09.797-05:00  INFO 19892 --- [           main] org.example.ApplicationKt                : Starting ApplicationKt using Java 17.0.8 with PID 19892
2024-01-18T07:46:09.804-05:00  INFO 19892 --- [           main] org.example.ApplicationKt                : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-18T07:46:11.339-05:00  INFO 19892 --- [           main] org.example.ApplicationKt                : Started ApplicationKt in 2.223 seconds (process running for 3.064)
```

I already tried adding grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure to the dependencies, same problem yet.

Does anyone already had a similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The `grpc-spring-boot-starter` is for Spring Boot 2.x and isn't compatible (apparently) with Spring Boot 3.x. The 2.15.0 version of the dependency uses Spring Boot 3.2 which might be compatible if not upgrade your spring boot version as well.

Comment: I think you are right - trying to find a solution here to use a newer version of spring-boot and grpc-spring-boot-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks M.Deinum.

Once I moved plugin and dependencies to 3.2.1 and grpc-spring-boot-starter to 2.15.0.Release everything seems to work fine.